# Unix epoch time with no timepart

Tags: apache-spark-sql

In one of my csv file I have column which is date value in form of unix epoc(So I think). One example value is `42034`. When I convert this value using function such as `from_unixtime` I get `1970-01-01 11:40:41`. What I really expect is `06-02-2015 00:00:00` as `mm-dd-yyyy`. I can see the column doesn't really have the unix epoch value. I am guessing the column has only date information and no time info.
Does any faced a similar issue and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The value in the column is integer value for date created from an excel file. So I ended up using xlrd module to convert to date. `xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime`.

```
import xlrd
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def xl_date_convert(d):
    return xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(changedD,0)
```